# Celery task ownership

Tags: celery, task, prefix, ownership

I am implementing api service, which handles users tasks. The user can create task, get task. I am using celery with Rabbitmq and Redis.

The problem: I have no way of checking if the task belongs to user or not.

My thoughts:

1. I can put user_id in the task argument and run update_state inside the task, and then check ownership every time someone triggers get_task method. The only problem is when task is not yet executed there will be no task.info and no user_id in it.
2. If the task id format in celery is not fixed to UUID, I could encode user id in the task id itself (user_id/task_id) and then check if the requester's user_id is the same as in task id. This looks like a much cleaner solution than the 1, but require the celery to user custom task id format.
3. Mirror the task to the database with all the required information about ownership (before triggering the task, simply create record about the task in the postgres database). This will require me to implement task - database syncronization, which seems to overcomplicate the solution.

Questions:

1. Can I prefix task id with arbitary text? Like in my case prefix my be user's id
2. What is a better way of implementing the service that I described?